# open downloaded file chrome extension ERROR Unchecked runtime.lastError: User gesture required

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am making a Chrome extension. I need it to open  the file automatically after downloading.

on console Error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: User gesture required

I don't have any notification or popup for gesture

Manifest v3

```
..."permissions": [ "notifications", "contextMenus", "storage" , "clipboardWrite", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting", "downloads",  "downloads.shelf"]...
```

I think problem because manifest v3 is not so good

my background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "reg",
    title: "Зарегистрировать письмо",
    contexts: ["link"],
}
);
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: info.linkUrl,
    },
        function (downloadId) { })
});
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function (downloadId) {
    if (downloadId.state.current == "complete") {
        chrome.downloads.open(downloadId.id)
    }
});
```

my simple code work on manifest v2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eFyl.jpg)
but on manifest v3 i don't have any notification or popup for gesture

Comment: It means you have to call chrome.downloads.open from an event initiated by the physical user like a click in a visible page or an event listed at the bottom of [activeTab page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/#invoking-activeTab).

Comment: Like contextMenus.onClicked? my background.js here. dont work

Comment: You can't make the decision for the user to open a downloaded file. That would be insecure. Imagine a malware author writing an extension that downloaded *and ran* their malware automatically with no input from the user...

Comment: i want gesture, but I don't have any notification or popup for gesture.  On Manifest v2 it work, popup for gesture.

Comment: The user gesture from onClicked is retained for 1 second, AFAIK, so if onChanged is fired later it won't be used. If the same works in ManifestV2 it could have been a bug which is now fixed.

Comment: it no bug, it right work.  why i I have not this notification for gesture. How i can gesture? try my simpe code on man v3 and man v 2 and you understand what I'm talking about.